# Ubuntu 20.10 isn't recognizing usb drive as mobile broadband

Tags: networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, 20.10

Recently I upgraded my distro to latest installation available, to escape some undesirable issues found on earlier version 20.04. But now I'm facing some unusual problem associated to my mobile broadband, since my first experience on Ubuntu 18.04 I never faced something similar. The system take to much time to detect my usb drive and doesn't recognize it as mobile broadband neither on system menu or networks settings. Pls, help!

Comment: It's a bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3203

Comment: Wow! 3.38.1 still not fixed...

Comment: 20.10 is not a LTS version I recommend using 20.04 and trying to solve whatever problems you have with it

Comment: I kinda tried to solve 'em... But it wasn't being productive. I heard that Ubuntu 20.10 was gonna be optimized for newer hardware and blazing fast, so decided to upgrade recently. The rumor after all was true! It may contain some unpleasant things at start but compared to earlier LTS version I think it's doing well though. Gnome shell uses less resources (RAM, CPU, etc) and memory leaks have been tracked and destroyed. Among others fantastic improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found temporary solution... For those who are facing the same issues follow this link: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-10-gnome-shell-modem-broadband-issue/19101

Answer (score -1):

seems like 20.10 didn't install tcl by default. I was able to fix the issue by install tcl

```
    sudo apt-get install tcl
```

I was getting the following error

```
usb_modeswitch@1-1.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
usb_modeswitch@1-1.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher: No such file or directory
```